# how is connection injected into the inline function of jdbctemplate.query?

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc

I saw code as the following,

```
List<UploadedDocument> docs = jdbcTemplate.query(
                connection -> {
                PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                stmt.setString(1, userName);
                return stmt;
            },
            this::getDocumentsFromResultSet
    );
```

I knew connection should database connection but could not find how it's created. It's not declared in the method or anywhere in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically no different from other `JdbcTemplate` methods where a query is executed without you explicitly needing to create or acquire a connection: Spring handles the creation/acquisition of the connection for you; it's made available to JdbcTemplate by Spring.

(The connection may have been created as part of a DB connection pool, when your app starts. But either way, all you have to provide are the connection properties.)

---

Looking more closely at your specific example, there *is* actually an explicit mention of a `connection` instance.

So, why is that?

It's because of the lambda expression used in the example.

The specific query method in the question is:

```
query(PreparedStatementCreator psc,  ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)
```

[Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query(org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCreator,org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper)).

(At least, I think that's a `ResultSetExtractor` - I can't see the implementation of `this::getDocumentsFromResultSet`. But that is not relevant here.)

Ignoring the `ResultSetExtractor`, if we look at [`PreparedStatementCreator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/PreparedStatementCreator.html), we see that is a functional interface - which is why we can use the lambda expression shown in the question.

The specific method is for this functional interface is:

```
createPreparedStatement(Connection con)
```

**That is where the connection object is provided** (by Spring):

The Javadoc states:

> This interface creates a PreparedStatement given a connection, provided by the JdbcTemplate class.

You get to *see* that reference - but you don't *create* it. You just *make use* of it to build your `PreparedStatement`.

---

It's possible the `JdbcTemplate` was [constructed using a `DataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#%3Cinit%3E(javax.sql.DataSource)) "*to obtain connections from*".

But again, you would not see any code in the `JdbcTemplate` relating to the creation of any connections, or acquiring a connection from the pool (if you are using a pool)>

---

**Extra Note**

Looking in the source code for `JdbcTemplate`, you can see where instances of that class acquire their database connection. Here is one example:

```java
Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(obtainDataSource());
```

See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/7d2047cdbd6f440cd2ce638947795c81c537db28/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L646).